# Trying to find a particular recent CSS layout grid system

Tags: css, grid

I recently came across a new grid system and seem to've lost the link. (It's new to me, though I'm fairly sure it is actually recent.) I'm hoping someone can help me dig it up again.

It was based on a pretty small grid increment, maybe 10px and was a bit different in also taking into consideration horizontal alignment. The homepage itself served as demo and had several buttons to toggle vertical and horizontal grid lines and a column image, together or in isolation. While the base increment was very small(as above), the grid overlay used lines of two weights to group sub-sections and produce a more reasonable/likely grid of ~40/50px.

I want to examine *this* system and am not interested in suggested alternatives, so to pre-emptively cut off a bunch of potential answers, I am **not** looking for: Blueprint, Tripoli, Atatonic, YAML, 520, 960, 1140, 1KB, Variable Grid System, BlueTrip, YUI Grids, Elastic, SenCSS, Golden Grid, Boilerplate, LogicCSS or any of the pre-processors(eg. LESS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found it again in my feeds: [The Square Grid](http://thesquaregrid.com/)